# (Swift) How to do a fuzzy search of Core Data?

Tags: ios, regex, swift, search, core-data

I'm trying to implement a search by Core Data key, in Swift. I want to get back relevant results, both exact and proximate, sorted in order of distance (from the closest match to the most distant).

For example, if someone searches for, say, "friend", I want the search results to look something like the following: "friend", "friends", "friendly", and "friand".

I've tried my best to implement such a search, but I'm fairly new to this sort of code, and my attempted implementation is not quite working for me at the moment. This is my code:

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "db")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dbKey MATCHES %@", ".*" + searchString + ".*")
var results: Array = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

if (results.count > 100) {
    results.removeRange(Range(start: 100, end: results.count-1))
}

var sortedResults: Array = [results[0]]

for (var i = 1; i < results.count; ++i) {
        if (countElements(results[i].valueForKey("dbKey") as String) < countElements(sortedResults[i-1].valueForKey("dbKey") as String)) {
        var j = i-1
        while (countElements(results[i].valueForKey("dbKey") as String) < countElements(sortedResults[j].valueForKey("dbKey") as String)) {
            if (j != 0) {
                --j
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
        sortedResults.insert(results[i], atIndex: j)
    } else {    
        sortedResults.append(results[i])
    }
}

results = sortedResults
```

The problem is twofold:

- Firstly, the results come back in no particular order, so if I search for "a", I'm going to get back a huge amount of words containing "a" long before I get the exact match. Since I cut off after the first 100 results, I never get the exact match to show up in my results.
- Secondly, the ranking is approximate. This is probably a maths error on my part, but currently, many longer words show up before shorter words, so you don't see exact or near-exact matches at the top of the results list, as you should.

I tried to find a library which would incorporate search functionality of the kind I am looking for (something like [Fuse.js](http://kiro.me/projects/fuse.html)), but I've had no luck. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm actually in the process of creating a Swift version of Fuse. Will that help? (full disclosure, I created Fuse.js)

Comment: @krisk — did you create the Swift version? It would be awesome :)

Comment: @jeff-h, here's the Swift version: https://github.com/krisk/fuse-swift

Comment: Yep, that's awesome :D

Answer (score 3):

You could filter your results using different predicates and decide which one to use;

- `let result = NSPredicate(format: "dbKey CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString)`
- `let result = NSPredicate(format: "dbKey startsWith[cd] %@", searchString)`
- `let result = NSPredicate(format: "dbKey LIKE '%@'", searchString)`

For particular order, you should use **NSSortDescriptor**

Answer (score 2):

Not an actual answer to your question, but a solution to what you're trying to do still: have a look at [PermissiveResearch](https://github.com/leverdeterre/PermissiveResearch).

It would look something like this:

```
extension UIViewController: PermissiveResearchDelegate {
    // Call this once
    func rebuildDatabase() {
        PermissiveResearchDatabase.sharedDatabase().delegate = self
        for db in allDbs { // Assuming allDbs is your array of DB objects
            PermissiveResearchDatabase.sharedDatabase().addManagedObject(db, forKey: "dbKey")
        }
    }

    // A basic search method
    func search(searchString: String) {
        PermissiveResearchDatabase.sharedDatabase().searchString(searchString, withOperation: ScoringOperationTypeExact)
    }

    // PermissiveResearchDelegate method
    func searchCompletedWithResults(results: [AnyObject]!) {
        let pResults = results as! [PermissiveCoreDataObject]
        for result in pResults {
            let db = try! self.managedObjectContext.existingObjectWithID(result.objectID) as! DB
            print("\(result.score) - \(db.dbKey)")
        }
    }
}
```